# epoch timestamp conversion in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm have normalized a json into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    id  main    description         icon    dt          feels_like
    0   801     Clouds  few clouds  02n     1628017200  19.21
    1   800     Clear   clear sky   01n     1628020800  19.37
    2   801     Clouds  few clouds  02n     1628024400  19.09
```

I want to convert the timestamp now into a readable format like : `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`

but the code does not work:

```
weather_data['dt'] = weather_data['dt'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
```

it gives me an error saying:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

What did I do wrong?

merci A

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the string to datetime using `pandas.to_datetime()` and then convert back to string in the desired format using `strftime`.

Try:

```
weather_data['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(weather_data['dt'],unit='s').dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

>>> weather_data['dt']
0    08/03/2021 19:00:00
1    08/03/2021 20:00:00
2    08/03/2021 21:00:00
Name: dt, dtype: object
```